# Dataframe to multiple dataframes or lists for unique index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that has two columns and I want to create a list containing all the values in the second column for the same value in column one.

If I have a dataframe that looks like:

| Type | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Cars | Toyota |
| Cars | Honda |
| Cars | Tesla |
| Fruits | Apple |
| Fruits | Orange |
| Countries | USA |
| Countries | Mexico |

So I want to be either be able to divide this datafram into three separate df for Cars, Fruits, and Countries. Or I want to have a list for Cars, Fruits, and Countries that would like this:

```
Cars = ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Tesla']
Fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange']
Countries = ['USA, 'Mexico']
```

This is just an example, my dataframe is huge so I want to have a function that does this without having to manually type in each Type. I tried looking up groupby function for pandas but don't think I was able to find how I can use it to do what I need to.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: look at groupby functionality

Comment: I did! But I am not understanding how I can use it correctly in this context.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: df.groupby('Type').agg(list)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
dict_ = df.groupby('Type').agg(list).T.to_dict()

for key in dict_:
  li_ = dict_.get(key).get("Item")
  globals()[key] = li_
```

Also, you can use locals depends on your scope :

```
dict_ = df.groupby('Type').agg(list).T.to_dict()

for key in dict_:
  li_ = dict_.get(key).get("Item")
  locals()[key] = li_
```

You can get :

```
locals()["Cars"]
Out[1]: ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Teska']

globals()["Cars"]
Out[2]: ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Teska']
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to solve your question :)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['Cars', 'Cars', 'Cars', 'Fruits', 'Fruits', 'Countries', 'Countries'],
                   'Item': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Tesla', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'USA', 'Mexico']})

grouped = df.groupby('Type')['Item'].apply(lambda tags:','.join(tags)).to_frame()
grouped['Item'] = grouped['Item'].str.split(',')

print(grouped)
```

Output:

[image: output]